# How do I stop HTML entities appearing in an e-mail client's subject header?

Tags: emails

If I send an email with `drupal_mail` with the subject header:

```
Let's go
```

It appears in my email client:

```
Let&#39;s go
```

This is okay:

```
Let’s go
```

The most convincing explanation I've read is:

> The behavior you are seeing is because the subject line is being run
>   through check_plain() (via t()), which calls the PHP function
>   htmlspecialchars().

Here's the [link](https://drupal.org/node/1971386#comment-7308562).

What changes should I make to my hook_mail code to correct my header in the email client:

```
$message['subject'] = t('Let's go');
```

**Code that threw the error:**

```
$message['subject'] = t('@responder has responded to: @title', array(
  '@responder' => $params['responder'],
  '@title' => $params['title'],
));
```

Comment: It's closed (fixed) on May 1, 2013 at 8:20am - at what Drupal version are you seeing the issue? And why won't you simply upgrade?

Comment: In current version the subject line is run through  `mime_header_encode()` that's mail-safe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in Core, apparently already fixed.

Comment: Hmmm, I using the latest version, but I still got &#39; in my subject header. Do you not get the same error when you send mail? Thanks.

Comment: My version is 7.23. I've added the exact line of code that threw the error (above). The offending apostrophe that caused the error would have been in the @title placeholder, if that's significant?

Comment: Now it looks like you haven't seen [this comment in the docs](https://api.drupal.org/comment/25348#comment-25348) - More complete version of Victor's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **!responder** and **!title** instead of **@responder** and **@title** in your code (by using ! instead @ or % it tells drupal to use the string as is ; by using @responder Drupal will run the string through check_plain to escape html characters).

Comment: So, I guess now someone can try to insert HTML into my email header and it won't be sanitized, but presumably an email client would not execute HTML in a subject header?

Comment: This is the best answer if you have access to the email subject line code (e.g your custom module). Otherwise, if that text is provided by another module, my answer below using `hook_mail_alter` may be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

If still an issue after upgrading, you can use

[`hook_mail_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7)

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter
 */
function MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  // Sanitize and decode HTML entities in email subject
  $message['subject'] = decode_entities(filter_xss($message['subject']));
}
```